# Listview starts from center instead of top left

Tags: android, xml

I don't have a gravity option for Listview and the closest is foreground gravity but that doesn't work either. How do I make the listview start from the top left where the arrow is, instead of from the middle?

[image]

```
content_xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.myname.appname.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textFilterEnabled="false"
        android:foregroundGravity="top|left" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Change the ListView's `layout_width` and `layout_height` to `match_parent`. You can also remove the `layout_center*` attributes.

Comment: @MikeM. Works. Thanks.

Comment: Remove android:layout_centerVertical="true" and change layout_width and layout_height to match_parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the listview `layout_width` and `layout_height` as `match_parent` this should fix the issue. Below code should work for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.myname.appname.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView"  
    android:textFilterEnabled="false" />
```